# SQL query - find where a value (where there could be multiple) does not exist

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I need some help in identifying records which do not have a specific value associated with it.

Need:
Each distinct customer record can have multiple methods of contact, for example:

```
Cheryl Hubert has the following contact records:
Code value: 1.  
Description: home phone   
CustomerData:. 123-456-7890

Code value: 2
Description: work phone
CustomerData: 000-123-4567

Code value:3
Description: email
CustomerData: chubert@xxx.xxx
```

Customers may have none of these, or some of these.

I need to write a query to find all those customer records which DO NOT have an email address (code value 3).  I've seen queries  with 'not exists' but not sure that would be the right way.  Keep in mind that the same field name is used for all contact data (CustomerData).

The code value/description provides what is within the `CustomerData` field.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try what you have seen first. If it doesn't work then post a question with description that which part it doesn't work as your expectation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say the contact info is in a table `contactRecords`, which looks something like this:

```
customerId int,    
codeValue int,
description varchar,
customerData varchar
```

To get all of the customers who do not have an email record (where `codeValue = 3`), try something like this:

```
select distinct customerId
from contactRecords 
where customerId not in (
     select distinct customerId
     from contactRecords
     where codeValue = 3)
```

The inner query finds all customers who have an email record. The outer query finds all *but* those customers.

Comment: That's it!  Thank you!

Comment: @CherylLHubert of course! When you get a chance, could you mark the answer as correct (by clicking the check mark)? That way, future readers will know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

As you posted almost no data i will try guessing your structure. Assuming you have clients in one table and contacts on another one with the client id, usually when you want to find something non relational between two tables, you select on your client, left join on your contact and put a where clause on any of the contact column is null.  If you want specifically the value 3, put it directly in join clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select * 
from customers c
where not exists(select 1 from contact_method
                 where customer_id = c.id
                 and description = 'email');
```

I assumed such schema:

```
create table customers(id int, name varchar(20));
insert into customers values (1, 'Cheryl Hubert');

create table contact_method (id int, customer_id int, code_value int, description varchar(20), customer_data varchar(20));
insert into contact_method values (1, 1, 1, 'home phone', '123-456-7890');
insert into contact_method values (2, 1, 2, 'work phone', '000-123-4567');
insert into contact_method values (3, 1, 3, 'email', 'chubert@xxx.xxx');
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1cfaa/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses to check:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE contact_details ( code_value, customerid, description, customerdata ) AS
  SELECT 1, 1, 'home phone', '123-456-7890' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 1, 'work phone', '000-123-4567' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 1, 'email',      'chubert@xxx.xxx' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 2, 'home phone', '012-345-6789' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT customerid
FROM   contact_details
GROUP BY customerid
HAVING COUNT( CASE description WHEN 'email' THEN 1 END ) = 0
```

**Output**:

```
| CUSTOMERID |
|------------|
|          2 |
```